# Select2 v4 and Bootstrap v4 - missing dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Trying to implement Select2 (v4) on Bootstrap (v4) page, but Dropdown is not rendered
on templateResult: formatState, though entries are shown in the Select2 Box.
And it's all fine in the reverse case when templateResult is not used.

The page is loaded via GET and java jsp.
jQuery:

```js
$("#country").select2({
  templateResult: formatState,
  templateSelection: formatStateOnChoose,
  placeholder: "select Country",
  dropdownAutoWidth : true
});
```

#### Libs I'm using:

- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js
- https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
- https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js

#### Pictures:

Test picture:

[image: test pic 1]

Result picture:

[image: result pic]

Comment: You can edit the post for the understandable post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was calling the same function "select2#formatState" in Bootstrap formatted page like in non Bootstrap page (was my older version of page). The issue was in "select2#formatState" - I forgot to add return statement! In older version this was okay for interpreter, but not in Bootstrap version. Nevertheless, this is a little bit strange that in older version this was acceppted.

In formatstate function I have coded a pseudo tree with some logic behind and this the function:

```
function formatState (state) {

if (!state.id) {
  return state.text;
}

let idents = state.id.split("&");
let codeId = idents[0].split("=");
let $state;

if (codeId[0] === 'BB' || codeId[0] === 'AA') {

    $state = $( '<span><img src="'+ baseUrl + idents[1] + '" height="10"      
             class="img-flag"/><b>&nbsp;' + state.text + '</b></span>');
} else if (codeId[0] === 'CC' ) {

    $state = $('<span style="padding-left:30px;"><img src="'+ baseUrl + idents[1]
            + '" height="10" class="img-flag"/>&nbsp;' + state.text + '</span>');
} else {

    $state = $('<span style="padding-left:15px;"><img src="'+ baseUrl + idents[1]  
            + '" height="10" class="img-flag"/>&nbsp;' + state.text + '</span>');
}
 return $state;  //<<--- missing  !!!
}
```